# store array of cllocation value in userdefaults iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, arrays, nsuserdefaults, cllocation

hi i have an array of cllocation values, i need to store that array in userdefaults...how do i do it...?
hi these where i add object to my array:
 [AM_locationMP.favArray addObject:[AM_locationMP.locationData objectAtIndex:AM_locationMP.indexno]];

where location data is array of location placemark values .

where maplocationVO class is for placemark 
MapLocationVO *currentMapLocation;

[AM_delegate.locationData addObject: currentMapLocation];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be enough to write it:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:yourArray forKey:@"clArray"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: i tried that but it gives  *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '( "<MapLocationVO: 0x169440>" )' of class '__NSArrayI'.

Comment: post your code then, where you declare yourArray and all the object you insert in it... the problem seems to be an inappropriate object somewhere...

Comment: yep the problem was an inappropriate object, what i was tring to do was inserting an nsobject class object into an array and storing that array into nsuserdefault, hence which according to doc does not come in userdefault specified list, hence solution was to archive the nsobject class. and it worked like charm thks ...for pointing me to rt direction

Answer (score 1):

Why do people post on here when they clearly don't know the answer, or understand what you can and cannot store in NSUserDefaults?

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData. For more details, see Preferences and Settings Programming Guide. -- From the documentation

You need to use NSKeyedArchiver to turn the CLLocation data into NSData. Then use NSKeyedUnarchiver to turn the NSData back into CLLocation data.

The next problem to solve is when you archive CLLocation objects and store them in UserDefaults, the don't unarchive properly. The only solution may be to save them to file instead.

Answer (score 0):

use this

for setting array

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

  [standardUserDefaults setObject:yourArray forKey:@"array"];
  [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

and for getting array

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

  [standardUserDefaults setObject:yourArray forKey:@"array"];

NSMutableArray *array=[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"array"];
```

Comment: have tried doing that but it gives *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
    "<MapLocationVO: 0x169440>"
)' of class '__NSArrayI'.

Comment: make array mutable by using mutableCopy function.

Comment: still am getting *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
    "<MapLocationVO: 0x1c5550>"
)' of class '__NSArrayM'.

Comment: you need to check your objects present in Array try to manage those objects and also make array as property of the class.

Comment: i am setting the property of array as nonatomic retain, and i do chk object of my array thn also same error ...

Comment: @devonsmith sorry bro without debugging i cant help you more than this.good luck